# Files has invalid value error, the given path's format is not supported

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am developing software with Visual Studio 2010. After saving and compiling my project, I received this error:

> Error  1   Files has invalid value "c:\users\mamma\documents\visual studio
>       2010\Projects\Contact_DDBB\Contact_DDBB\obj\x86\Debug\
>       GeneratedInternalc:\users\mamma\documents\visual studio2010\Projects\Contact_DDBB_\
>       Contact_DDBB\bin\Debug\Contact_DDBB.exe". The given path's format is not supported. 
>       Contact_DDBB

I don't know which kind of error it is and why it has appeared.

What's the nature of this error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: That's a __long__ path.  It appears you have two separate paths concatenated into one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try clearing your project, these kind of things happen on Visual Studio All the time. You should be able to do this by going to Build > Clean Solution

Hope it works!

Comment: i tried to follow your way but i receive this error :C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3597,9): error MSB3541: Files has invalid value "c:\users\mamma\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Contact_DDBB_@Xavi\Contact_DDBB_@Xavi\obj\x86\Debug\GeneratedInternalc:\users\mamma\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Contact_DDBB_@Xavi\Contact_DDBB_@Xavi\bin\Debug\Contact_DDBB_@Xavi.exe". The given path's format is not supported. Do you have any idea?Thanks so much

Comment: It shouldnt happen, but seems tha VS doesnt handles files quite well. Ive goggled "Visual Studio error MSB3541" and i see some promissing pages. You should check that way.

Answer (score 17):

just delete obj and bin subfolders in the project folder and recompile the project again. 
It seems that a file name or sth in those paths are corrupted and cannot be listed by C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3597,9)

Answer (score 1):

manually clear and save following file
projectname.vbproj.FileListAbsolute.txt

location
project path\obj\x86\Debug\

effective in all cases
such as Build,Rebuild and Clear is failed